# How to Attach Sides to Rabbit Pen

Tags: joinery, technique, design

I am making my daughter's rabbit her own "room".  I bought some pressure treated plywood and made a 6' x 6' square and covered it with fake grass.  Put a bunch of 2x4s under it, and put 12" x 3/4" shelving on the sides so she could kick stuff out of it.  That's the base, and it turned out pretty good.  It is sitting in the corner of the room, so it had walls on two sides, and I want to make sides for the other two.
[image: Base Design]

[image: Completed Base]

My idea is to build the frame with 1"x4" wood.  I'd staple 1"x1" welded stainless steel wire mesh to it, and them  put another 1"x4" frame on the other side and screwed into each other.  My thoughts are this...  First, the welded wire mesh will hold up a lot better than the cheap chicken wire crap on the old hutch.  Secondly, if it's between two layers it can't just pop off with pressure from one side.  Lastly two layers of 1"x4" will give me a stronger (than a single layer of 1"x4" or 1"x2") side without being TOO bulky.
[image: Side Design]

I have two questions.  One main one, and a smaller one.
The big question is... How do I attach the corners where the two sides meet?  I will put a 2"x2" on the actual walls and anchor one side of the sides to them.  I will also attach the bottom of the sides to the 3/4" shelving  that surrounds the base.  Do I make one longer and screw it into the other?  I'm worried that with only 1" thickness that it won't hold well.  My other thought was to put a 4"x4" on the inside corner there, add some shelving scraps so it's even with the outer shelf surround, and then attach them to that screwing through both layers and into the 4"x4".  I think that's an "easy" solution, but then I have a 4x4 sitting in the corner of her room :(

Lastly, I have a board running down the center of the side.  Looking at a butt joint there I believe.  Best way to attach those?  I considered pocket holes, but thought that 1" might be too thin for that.

I really appreciate your thoughts and opinions.  I want to get started on this this weekend so I'm hoping you can help me out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. I mainly wanted to say to include the images within the Question, something greatly appreciated here on SE because external links go stale so easily, but also that's a whole wall o' text you have there! While you're making the edit to include the images you could do with clipping this to remove the chatty/story bits so there's more focus on the actual question at hand.

Comment: I know you want to get started on this over the weekend and it's v. slow here, so in case nobody else chimes in with an Answer you can use anything sold as wood glue (PVA type or foaming polyurethane) or Liquid Nails. For a project like this it probably doesn't matter which you go with. And yes, glue and pins is enough. The longer the nails the stronger the reinforcement, but even skinny 1" brads add a lot to the mitres, and more so if you drive them in both ways.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks!  I added the link b/c my images were too big.  My scanner is on the fritz so I took them with my camera.  I'll edit and resave the images to make them smaller so I can add them and clean up the text.  I spend a lot off time in the coding exchanges and they want to know everything :P

Comment: If you ever need to resize images sort of on the fly, you can use Imgur itself to do this. Not sure about if you're not logged in (or don't have an account) but definitely when logged in resizing uploads is one of the options provided when adding images to your gallery.

Comment: @Graphus I recently got the imgur account and haven't played with it much.  I usually just edit in Photoshop.  I resized images and added inline.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Something to consider - rabbits like to chew. P/T lumber probably isn't the best thing for them to chew on. Modern pressure treating chemicals are much less toxic than they used to be, but little Hopper has a lot less body mass for the chemicals to build up in than even your daughter does. You don't want the fluffy guy to stop hopping prematurely. (Then again, having owned a "self-propelled Pez dispenser" as we called him, maybe you do... ;)